# Access DOM element "onSubmit" button click using Jquery in AngularJS 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

How can i access Jquery on button click event of angularjs 2.0?
Check my code, that I've done.

```js
import {Component, View, ElementRef, OnInit}   from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

elementRef: ElementRef;

constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.elementRef = elementRef;
}

onSignup() {            
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#register-box').css({height:"0", opecity:"0"});
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#success-box').css({height:"100%", opecity:"1"});      
  }
  
}
```

but this gives error like, 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: Can you check that argument passed to the constructor is not `undefined`?

Comment: console.log(elementRef); is defined but  console.log(elementRef.nativeElement); is not defined

Comment: how can i define elementRef.nativeElement?

Comment: Please see my answer, maybe it is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by below code,

```js
onSignup() {    
    var _this = this.model;

    if(Factory.signup(this.model).then(function(response) {if(response['status']){_this._id = response['result']; return true;}else{return false;};}))
    {
      jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#success-box').css({height: "100%",opacity: "1"});
      jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#register-box').css({height: "0",opacity: "0"});
    }
  }
```